# Custom metadata urls for ERC1155 tokens

Tags: nft, erc-1155

I have create a very basic ERC1155 token from this tutorial:

> https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/3.x/erc1155

```
// contracts/GameItems.sol
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC1155/ERC1155.sol";

contract GameItems is ERC1155 {
    uint256 public constant GOLD = 0;
    uint256 public constant SILVER = 1;
    uint256 public constant THORS_HAMMER = 2;
    uint256 public constant SWORD = 3;
    uint256 public constant SHIELD = 4;

    constructor() public ERC1155("https://game.example/api/item/{id}.json") {
        _mint(msg.sender, GOLD, 10**18, "");
        _mint(msg.sender, SILVER, 10**27, "");
        _mint(msg.sender, THORS_HAMMER, 1, "");
        _mint(msg.sender, SWORD, 10**9, "");
        _mint(msg.sender, SHIELD, 10**9, "");
    }
}
```

As you can see, 5 tokens are created when the contract is deployed.
Each of this 5 token is associated to a metadata file:

```
https://game.example/api/item/0000.....0001.json
https://game.example/api/item/0000.....0002.json
https://game.example/api/item/0000.....0003.json
https://game.example/api/item/0000.....0004.json
https://game.example/api/item/0000.....0005.json
```

I want to customize this 5 urls. They need to be very different.
Is it possible ?
I can override ERC1155 functions but i want to be compliant to ERC1155 in order to keep my token compatible with market places.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can make changes in the functions (e.g. changing the metadata URL), but you cannot change the number/types of input arguments nor return values, because this would violate the interface (see [Function Overriding](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/contracts.html#function-overriding) for more details).

Note that if you were inheriting from ERC1155Mintable, you could also call [`setURI`](https://github.com/enjin/erc-1155/blob/678092281094b7cd5328b417c677be05338ea0d6/contracts/ERC1155Mintable.sol#L71) to update your metadata URLs.

Comment: In your example setURI is an empty function (just contain an event emit...)

Comment: Yes, it's a minimal example. You would probably also add a `_setURI` call like in the ERC1155 constructor. If you just want to replace "https://game.example/api/item/{id}.json" with something else, you can change it right there in the `GameItems` constructor argument (just make sure it contains `{id}`).